# Celery Tasks are executing multiple times in Django Application

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have a Django application where I defined a few `@task` functions under `task.py` to execute at given periodic task. I'm 100% sure that the issue is not caused by `task.py` or any code related but due to some configuration may be in `settings.py` or my celery worker.

Task does execute at periodic task but at multiple times.

Here are the celery worker logs:

`celery -A cimexmonitor worker --loglevel=info -B -c 4`

```
[2019-09-19 21:22:16,360: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-5] Project Monitor Started : APPProject1
[2019-09-19 21:22:16,361: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Project Monitor Started : APPProject1
[2019-09-19 21:25:22,108: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Project Monitor DONE : APPProject1
[2019-09-19 21:25:45,255: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-5] Project Monitor DONE : APPProject1
[2019-09-20 00:22:16,395: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Project Monitor Started : APPProject2
[2019-09-20 00:22:16,398: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-5] Project Monitor Started : APPProject2
[2019-09-20 01:22:11,554: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-5] Project Monitor DONE : APPProject2
[2019-09-20 01:22:12,047: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Project Monitor DONE : APPProject2
```

- If you check above time interval, tasks.py executes one task but 2 workers of celery takes the task & executes the same task at the same interval. I'm not sure why 2 workers took for one task?
- settings.py

```
..
..
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
..
..
..
######## CELERY : CONFIG
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

- celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery 
import os
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','cimexmonitor.settings')
## set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.

# Using a string here means the worker don't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.

app = Celery('cimexmonitor')
#app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY') 
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

- Other information:

```
→ celery --version
4.3.0 (rhubarb)

→ redis-server --version
Redis server v=3.0.6 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=7785291a3d2152db

django-admin-interface==0.9.2
django-celery-beat==1.5.0
```

- Please help me the ways to debug the problem:

Thanks

Comment: could you test if your `celery.py` file is being loaded more than one time in your application?

Comment: Thanks for the response,How do i verify if `celery.py` is being loaded multiple times.

Comment: What command are you using to run `celerybeat`?

Comment: `celery -A appname beat --loglevel=debug --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler` for scheduler & `celery -A appname worker --loglevel=info -B -c 4` for worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the worker and beat services need to be running at the same time to execute periodically task as per `https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat`

- WORKER:

```
 $ celery -A [project-name] worker --loglevel=info -B -c 5
```

- Django scheduler:

```
celery -A [project-name] beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

- I was running both worker,database scheduler at same time, which was said as per the documentation, Which was causing the issues to be executed at the same time, I'm really not sure how `celery worker` started working as a DB scheduler at the same time.
- just running `celery worker` solved my problem.

Comment: Does not your solution break Celery Beat?

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation: [*Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time*](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time).

Also, I hope you are not running multiple workers the same way (`celery -A cimexmonitor worker --loglevel=info -B -c 4`) as that would mean you have multiple celery beats scheduling tasks to run... In short - make sure you only have one Celery beat running!

Comment: That's a different case.

Comment: Second part of my answer looks the same as your accepted answer... We could only guess what was the reason for your problem and it turns out I guessed right...